# python 2.2 find string after linebreak

Tags: python, regex, search, python-2.x

I have 2 strings that contains the following:

```
name = 'Kalvo'
info = 'PC1:\nKalvo (Read)(Write)\nKL27 (Read)(Write)'
```

Now what I want achieve here is to search the info for the word found in name and print out everything after name.

Lets say I'm searching the string info for string name and it should the print out:

```
Kalvo (Read)(Write)
```

Problem here is the python version I'm using is an old 2.2 version. With newer version of python this gets the job done:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> name = 'Kalvo'
>>> info = 'PC1:\nKalvo (Read)(Write)\nKL27 (Read)(Write)'
>>> findall("{}.*".format(name), info)[0]
'Kalvo (Read)(Write)'
```

But that doesn't work with older versions of python, how can achieve the same output with older version of python?

Comment: Wow, Python 2.2 is *very* old indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`%` string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) instead:

```
findall("%s.*" % name, info)[0]
```

or even just concatenation:

```
findall(name + ".*", info)[0]
```

The `re` module itself was [already present in 2.2](http://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/module-re.html).

Note that you probably want to use `re.escape()` on the string to make sure that any meta characters are escaped:

```
findall("%s.*" % re.escape(name), info)[0]
```